# Significato di "dar di mazza" o "menare di mazza"

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *Storia di San Benedetto da Norcia* di *Mistero buffo*, di Dario Fo, ho letto:

> A questo punto mastro santo Benedetto chiama tutti a un raduno e dice ai monaci:
>    
>         – Qua bisogna porre rimedio... voi ben comprendete che se 
>   pure il nostro fratello Cuoco che ci fa da mangiare se ne vola fuori nel cielo, ci ritroviamo al disastro. Fra poco qui non 
>   resterà piú nessuno! È chiaro che non riusciamo a trarre alcun vantaggio e salvamento né con pietre, con ancore, né 
>   affrancati ai carri. L’unica ancora vera che ci può salvare è 
>   codesta! – e il santo prende da contro il muro una vanga, la 
>   posa nelle mani di un monaco e dice: – Tieni! Prenditi quest’arnese qua e non ti capiterà più di levarti in volo!
>   
>         – Maestro santo, – gli dice il monaco Bonifacio, – non è 
>   abbastanza greve questa vanga che ci faccia da zavorra!
>   
>         – È vero, se tu la tieni a penzoloni! Ma se tu provi a **dar di mazza** a frangi terra e spingi con il piede e sollevi le zolle e le rivolti, tu scoprirai tosto quanto pesa e si fa greve! 
>   Provateci tutti quanti a prendervi una zappa e questo rastrello e anche voi altri... queste pale e questi forconi. Dateci con forte braccio e schiena, ficcatele nel terreno e **menate di mazza** sulle pietre. Spingete carriole, costruite 
>   muri, rizzate gli arconi di contrafforte. Montate una murata tonda intorno a quella grotta per farci un forno per il pane e i mattoni. Coraggio!... Issa!... Batti!... Stronca!... Alza!... Scarna!... Issa!... Ascoltate ora il sudore che vi sorte goccia a goccia dalla fronte alle braccia e cosí state sicuri che non vi riuscirà di levarvi nemmeno di un palmo in volo!

Questa storia parla di certi monaci che stanno cercando di porre fine a un loro problema: avevano raggiunto una cosí forte condizione mistica, che finivano sempre col levitare e perdersi volando nel cielo.

Nei dizionari ho trovato che "mazza" può essere un grosso bastone, ma non riesco a capire cosa voglia dire "dar di mazza" o "menare di mazza". Significa percuotere la terra con la vanga come se fosse un bastone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Dar di mazza" e "menare di mazza" significa usare la vanga come se fosse una mazza, che è un grosso martello per spaccare le pietre, per eliminarle dal terreno.

Se i monaci non tenevano la vanga a penzoloni ma cominciano a scavare nel terreno vedrai come si accorgono di quanto sia dura la vita di coloro che lo fanno tutti i giorni per sopravvivere.

"Dar di mazza" può, in altri casi, anche significare mettersi a lavorare di buona lena e con impegno.